# react-scripts build failing when updating from 1.x to 3.0.1

Tags: reactjs, npm

I'm trying to migrate [`react-scripts`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#migrating-from-300-to-301) from my current version (`1.1.4`) to the latest `3.0.1` for obvious reasons, but I'm having a hell of a time.

Here's my current, build successful `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "homepage": ".",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "ajv": "^6.9.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "axios-debug": "0.0.4",
    "date-fns": "^1.30.1",
    "formik": "1.2.0",
    "history": "4.7.2",
    "moment": "2.22.2",
    "localforage": "1.7.3",
    "prettier": "1.14.2",
    "react": "^16.8.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "0.32.4",
    "react-checkbox-group": "4.0.1",
    "react-datetime": "2.15.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "react-render-debugger": "1.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.87.1",
    "styled-components": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-hash-link": "1.2.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

So I'm using `npm` so running `npm install --save --save-exact react-scripts@3.0.1` installs the new `react-scripts` version, everything is updated correctly. I updated a few other packages that were needed as deps. No security vulnerabilities, everything was clean and installed correctly.

I'm using maven as a build system to build my app, once it tries to execute `npm run build` it fails on `react-scripts build`

The debug log is super unhelpful. The only error displayed is `/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts: Permission denied`

I've tried changing the permissions using `chmod +x /node_modules/.bin/react-scripts` but no luck.

I've tried deleting `node_modules` several times and reinstalling the modules using `npm ci`. Just about any issue I've found on github I've tried.

I'm not sure what else could be wrong.

Using node v11.9.0 and npm 6.5.0

Do I need to update in smaller version increments? I'm really at a loss

**EDIT**:
Something is wrong with `npm` in my case. <strike>Manually updating the package versions in `package.json` seems to work for now...</strike> I need to figure out why `npm` is broken for me

Comment: Well after trying everything, I just ran `yarn` inside the dir with `node_modules` and `package.json` and it worked.